# Пишу погодного бота, ошибка During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Tags: python

Пишу погодного бота, перепроверил код 10 раз. Сохраняю, запускаю пишет введите город:, ввожу и примерно через 10 секунд вместо погоды выдает ошибку.

[image: Код]

Заранее прошу прощения если сделал что то не так, но над ошибкой уже бьюсь 2 дня, переустанавливал питона 3 раза, создавал новые погодные ключи.

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'

place = input("Введите название города: ")
owm = OWM('a352ccfa8e5cc6a0b20ff96a2d8069cb')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather

t = w.temperature("celsius")
t1 = t['temp']
t2 = t['feels_like']
t3 = t['temp_max']
t4 = t['temp_min']

wi = w.wind()['speed']
humi = w.humidity
cl = w.clouds
st = w.status
dt = w.detailed_status
ti = w.reference_time('iso')
pr = w.pressure['press']
vd = w.visibility_distance

print("В городе " + str(place) + " температура " + str(t1) + " °C" +     "\n" + 
"Максимальная температура " + str(t3) + " °C" +"\n" + 
"Минимальная температура " + str(t4) + " °C" + "\n" + 
"Ощцщается как" + str(t2) + " °C" + "\n" +
"Скорость ветра " + str(wi) + " м/с" + "\n" + 
"Давление " + str(pr) + " мм.рт.ст" + "\n" + 
"Влажность " + str(humi) + " %" + "\n" + 
"Видимость " + str(vd) + "  метров" + "\n" +
"Описание " + str(st) + "\n\n" + str(dt))
```

[image: Текст ошибки]

Comment: Добрый вечер, желательно видеть Ваш код и текст ошибку в виду текста, а не скриншотов

Comment: Добрый вечер, перенес код в текст. Заранее спасибо

Comment: нет ответа от сервера. Дело не в коде. Код рабочий. Мои предположения что вас блокируют по IP.

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже вчера об этом подумал. Сейчас буду думать как обойти

Comment: Поставил нужную программ по подмене ip и все заработало. Вот такие вот дела........